# Swift 4 ,must be used from main thread only warning

Tags: appdelegate, swift4, xcode9

When I using `Swift4`in `Xcode 9` gives me

> UIApplication.delegate must be used from main thread only
>
> .... must be used from main thread only
>
> UI API called from background thread Group

Purple Warning.

My codes;

```
var appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
public var context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
let prefs:UserDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
var deviceUUID = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!.uuidString
```

Warning line is;

```
  public var context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
```

Another warning like this;

```
 let parameters = [
                        "tel": "\(self.phone.text!)"
                        ] as [String : String]
```

Gives

> UITextField.text must be used from main thread only

Same error again..

How can I fix it ?  Any idea ?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You're making this call on a background queue. To fix, try something like…

```
public var context: NSManagedObjectContext

DispatchQueue.main.async {

    var appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext        
}
```

Although this is a pretty bad way to do this… you're using your App Delegate as a global variable (which we all know is bad!)

You should look at passing the managed object context from view controller to view controller…

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: 

    (window?.rootViewController as? MyViewController)?.moc = persistentContainer.viewContext
}
```

and so on

Comment: gives Attribute 'public' can only be used in a non-local scope error

Comment: Did you try removing `public`?

Comment: Gives many error in app, that codes in my settings.swift file this file not class, I need to move that codes in app delegate ?

Comment: when I use that codes gives me ;   Expressions are not allowed at the top level